# i got a error Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, authentication

here i am trying to create login page.
where only admin can access this page and currently admin name is akshay.
cs code of login page:

```
string cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString;
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(cnn);

        string IdText = UserName.Text;
        string PassText = Password.Text;

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from ab_db.login where user= @user and Pass = @Pass", con);
        con.Open();

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", MySqlDbType.String);
        cmd.Parameters["@user"].Value = UserName.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pass", MySqlDbType.String);
        cmd.Parameters["@Pass"].Value = Password.Text;

        MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        dr.Read();
        if (dr["user"].ToString().Trim() == IdText && dr["Pass"].ToString().Trim() == PassText)
        {
            Session["User"] = IdText;
            Response.Redirect("~/test2.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            FailureText.Text = "Invalid Username or Password";
        }

        dr.Close();
        con.Close();
```

and the page which i want to be safe is test2.
code is:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["User"] == "akshay")
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // Call FillGridView Method

            FillGridView();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // No valid login...
        Session.Clear();
        Response.Redirect("~/myLogin.aspx");
    }


}
```

bout i got a error which i cant understand why? please help.

the error is-

Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the result of `Read()`

```
if (dr.Read())
{
    // 
}
```